# create multi target nuget package

Tags: nuget, nuget-package, nuget-spec

hi i want create multi target nuget package. Everything seems to work well Except that whene i create wpf NetCore3 app and install my package The .NET Framework dll is used and The NetCore3 library is not used

```
<files>
    <file src="lib\netcore\Control.dll" target="lib\netcore" />
    <file src="lib\net48\Control.dll" target="lib\net48" />
    <file src="lib\net40\Control.dll" target="lib\net40" />
    <file src="lib\net40\Microsoft.Windows.Shell.dll" target="lib\net40" />
  </files>
```

Is this **lib\netcore** correct?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

[`netcore` is a Microsoft Store TFM](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/nuget/reference/target-frameworks#supported-frameworks).

For your .NET Core 3 (`netcoreapp3.0`) WPF app, you'd need to multi-target with `netstandard` or `netcoreapp` in your NuGet package.

For example:

`<TargetFrameworks>netstandard2.0;net461</TargetFrameworks>`

Answer (score 1):

You should use the same TFM in the package as your `csproj` has in the `<TargetFramework>` element. If your `csproj` has `<TargetFramework>netcore</TargetFramework>`, then sure, use `lib/netcore/whatever.dll`. But if your `csproj` has `<TargetFramework>netcoreapp3.0</TargetFramework`>, then you should use `lib/netcoreapp3.0/whatever.dll`.

However, SDK style projects, the only type that work with .NET Core 3.0, support multi-targeting (change `<TargetFramework>` to `<TargetFrameworks>`, then use a semicolon delimited list `netcoreapp3.0;net48;net40`), and NuGet's pack targets know how to pack these projects automatically. So there is no need to create a `nuspec` yourself, which minimises the risk of making these types of mistakes.

So, just as [NuGet's docs on creating multi-targeting packages](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/nuget/create-packages/multiple-target-frameworks-project-file) says, just use `dotnet pack` to create your package, and let NuGet figure out what `lib/*` folders to use. Avoid using nuspec files. Any other metadata you specify in the nuspec can [specified via MSBuild properties in your csproj](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/nuget/reference/msbuild-targets#pack-target).